# Excel Finding Average value based on multiple criteria (multiple values)

Tags: excel

Table:

```
      Name Price New/Old
      A    10     Y
      A    20     N
      B    35     Y
      B    45     Y
      C    50     N
      C    60     Y
```

If I want to find: The average price when name = A and New/Old = Y:

```
 IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7, "A", $C$2:$C$7, "Y"),"") = 10
```

Which is relevantly easy.

However, I got stuck when finding the average price when name = A or B and New/Old = Y.

The correct answer is supposed to be: (10+35+45)/3 = 30

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is easily doable in programming languages like R/SQL/Python.  But this report is needed to be done in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more direct approach using an array:

`=AVERAGE(IF((($A$2:$A$7="A")+($A$2:$A$7="B")+($C$2:$C$7="Y"))=2,$B$2:$B$7))`

Remember to enter an array formula hold `Shift` + `Ctrl` and hit `Enter`

Comment: Hi Simon,

Thank you for your time again. Would you mind to explain to me what does "=2" mean in this case? 

Sorry, I'm not really good with excel.

Comment: The `=2` means that 2 of the preceding criteria must be true (each of the three criteria return 1 if true and 0 if false), as column A can only be EITHER `A` or `B` then if it equals one or the other then `1` is returned, if column C = `Y` that returns 1, added to the other 1 you get the `=2`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could also use this array formula `=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A7={"A","B"},IF(C2:C7="Y",B2:B7)))` - which might be preferable if you have a longer list of criteria for col A

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an easier/ more eloquent way, but this should do it:

```
=(SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7, "A", $C$2:$C$7, "Y")+SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7, $A$2:$A$7, 
    "B", $C$2:$C$7, "Y"))/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7, "A", $C$2:$C$7, "Y")+
    COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7, "B", $C$2:$C$7, "Y"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Simon. Indeed your solution works, but I was actually looking for a bit more direct approach.

Comment: Since the actual data is quite large, and it will get ugly. :(

Comment: Added a separate answer as I figured a more direct approach

Answer (score 1):

Non-array formula

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,TRANSPOSE({"A","B"}),C2:C7,"Y"))/
 SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,TRANSPOSE({"A","B"}),C2:C7,"Y"))
```

Simon's is neater though

Edit: after Barry's comment

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,{"A","B"},C2:C7,"Y"))/SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,{"A","B"},C2:C7,"Y"))
```

Comment: You don't really need the `TRANSPOSE` functions, Tim - the formula will work with just {"A","B"} or {"A";"B"}

Comment: @barryhoudini - thanks: thought I'd tested without and it hadn't worked - seems it does!